# Combining and grouping data from two XML files

Tags: xquery

I have an XML file **bands.xml** as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<bands>
  <band>
    <name>Metallica</name>
    <nationality>American</nationality>
  </band>
  <band>
    <name>Marilyn Manson</name>
    <nationality>American</nationality>
  </band>
</bands>
```

and another file listing their albums **albums.xml** as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<albums>
  <album>
    <title>Master of Puppets</title>
    <band>Metallica</band>
    <date>1986</date>
    <genre>rock</genre>
  </album>
  <album>
    <title>St. Anger</title>
    <band>Metallica</band>
    <date>2003</date>
    <genre>rock</genre>
  </album>
  <album>
    <title>The Golden Age of Grotesque</title>
    <band>Marilyn Manson</band>
    <date>2004</date>
    <genre>rock</genre>
  </album>
  <album>
    <title>Mechanical Animals</title>
    <band>Marilyn Manson</band>
    <date>1998</date>
    <genre>pop</genre>
  </album>
</albums>
```

What I wish to do is combine these 2 XML files into another processed XML file. The Xquery will list down all bands, and within it list all the albums associated with that particular band, group it by album genre (sorted alphabetically). This is further illustrated as in the XML file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<bands>
  <band>
    <name>Metallica</name>
    <nationality>American</nationality>
    <albums genre="rock">
      <album date="1986">
        <title>Master of Puppets</title>
      </album>
      <album date="2003">
        <title>St. Anger</title>
      </album>
    </albums>
  </band>
  <band>
    <name>Marilyn Manson</name>
    <nationality>American</nationality>
    <albums genre="pop">
      <album date="1998">
        <title>Mechanical Animals</title>
      </album>
    </albums>
    <albums genre="rock">
      <album date="2004">
        <title>The Golden Age of Grotesque</title>
      </album>
    </albums>
  </band>
</bands>
```

What I've managed to do is get all the band details part, and also list all associated albums produced by that band. However since I am using Xquery 1.0, it is really frustrating to group the albums according to genre!

Comment: Where is your XQuery?

Comment: Does your XQuery processor support XQuery 3.0 (where `group by` was introduced)? If you do not know, which XQuery processor are you using? I am not entirely sure you can achieve what you want using purely XQuery 1.0.

Comment: Sadly, I am using **XQuery 1.0**! :( I have seen examples how people mimic `group by` by using recursive `for` loops, but I really don't understand what they are doing.

Comment: What processor are you using?  Here is a resource that might help. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Grouping_Items

Comment: I'm using Kawa 1.9.1 which supports XQuery 1.0

Comment: I just edited your question title. Actually, your question has nothing to do with group by - Obviously it throws an error, as it is not supported by XQuery 1.0

Comment: Marilyn Manson's TGAoG was released in 2003. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work using purely XQuery 1.0:

```
declare variable $bandsxml  := doc("bands.xml");
declare variable $albumsxml := doc("albums.xml");
<bands>
{
  for $findband in $bandsxml/bands/band
  return 
    <band>
    {
      $findband/name, 
      $findband/nationality, 
      let $albums-per-band := $albumsxml/albums/album[band = $findband/name]
      for $genre in distinct-values($albums-per-band/genre)
      order by $genre
      let $albums := $albums-per-band[genre = $genre]

      return element {"albums"} {
        attribute {"genre"} {$genre},
        attribute {"active"} {string-join((xs:string(min($albums/date)), "-", xs:string(max($albums/date))), "")},
        attribute {"count"} {count($albums)},
        for $album in $albums
        return element {"album"} {
          attribute {"date"} {$album/date},
          $album/title
        }
      }
    }
    </band>
}
</bands>
```

In the first for loop it gets all distinct genres per band. It then uses this information and `$albums` is a sequence of albums for one particular band having a certain genre.

Comment: Error occurred at this line: `attribute {"active"} {string-join((xs:string(min($albums/date)), "-", xs:string(max($albums/date))))},` due to `call to 'string-join' has too few arguments (1; must be 2)` but comment that out and that is exactly what I was expecting! Thanks!

Comment: @samsulfreude I updated my answer, the second argument can be a simply empty string and it should work. A single argument version of string-join was introduced in XQuery 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in XQuery 3.0:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $bands := <bands>
  <band>
    <name>Metallica</name>
    <nationality>American</nationality>
  </band>
  <band>
    <name>Marilyn Manson</name>
    <nationality>American</nationality>
  </band>
</bands>

let $albums := <albums>
  <album>
    <title>Master of Puppets</title>
    <band>Metallica</band>
    <date>1986</date>
    <genre>rock</genre>
  </album>
  <album>
    <title>St. Anger</title>
    <band>Metallica</band>
    <date>2003</date>
    <genre>rock</genre>
  </album>
  <album>
    <title>The Golden Age of Grotesque</title>
    <band>Marilyn Manson</band>
    <date>2004</date>
    <genre>rock</genre>
  </album>
  <album>
    <title>Mechanical Animals</title>
    <band>Marilyn Manson</band>
    <date>1998</date>
    <genre>pop</genre>
  </album>
</albums>

return 
element { 'bands' } {
    for $findband in $bands//band
    return 
    element { 'band' } {
        $findband/name, 
        $findband/nationality, 
        for $findalbum in $albums//album
        let $genre := $findalbum/genre/text()
        where $findalbum/band = $findband/name
        group by $genre
        order by $genre
        return 
        element { 'albums' } {
            attribute { 'genre' } { $genre },
            attribute { 'active' } { fn:min($findalbum/date/text()) ||'-' || fn:max($findalbum/date/text()) }, 
            attribute { 'count' } { fn:count($findalbum) }, 
            for $album in $findalbum
            return
            element { 'album' } {
                attribute { 'date' } { $album/date/text()},
                $album/title
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but my processor doesn't support XQuery 3.0, so I can't test these, unfortunately.